# No more data to read from socket while copy data form one database to another using Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

In my application I am using multiple databases. From one database I load an object and in another database I save an object. I used different databases and get different errors each time.

In one case I got `sql error 0600`. In another case I got `table or view does not exist`. In one another case I got `No more data to read from socket`.

This error occurs only in case of one table. All others works well. Select query is working on the specific table but update and insert query causes error.

I an using Hibernate to do this.

Comment: Please include more context and details.

Comment: I am using map to save sessionfactory and getsession according to key.Now i get session from database say(192.168.2.64) and load an object of RegistrationVO.java from this database and after that i get a session from different database say(192.168.2.68) and run a saveOrUpdate method on previously loaded object.this causes error  that i tell you before